# How to select child element of each li in an each.do list iteration?

Tags: ruby, selenium, foreach, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I need to run through a list of users and open each in a new tab. The tab should close upon performing an action and return to the first tab to select the next user in the list. I'm having trouble selecting the next user in the list by order. The problem is that each user can be selected only by clicking their photo- which is a child element of the list item.

HTML

```
<div class="_gs38e">
 <ul class="_8q670 _b9n99">

  <li class="_6e4x5">
   <div class="_npuc5">
    <a class="_pg23k _9irns _gvoze" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
     <img class="_rewi8" src="https://pic.com/t51.2885-
     _1930374081979351040.jpg"></a>
    <div class="_eryrc">
     <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8" title="username1_" 
     href="/username1_/">username1_</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>

  <li class="_6e4x5">
   <div class="_npuc5">
    <a class="_pg23k _9irns _gvoze" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
     <img class="_rewi8" src="https://pic.com/t51.2885-
     _1930374081979351040.jpg"></a>
    <div class="_eryrc">
     <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8" title="username1_" 
     href="/username1_/">username1_</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>

  <li class="_6e4x5">
   <div class="_npuc5">
    <a class="_pg23k _9irns _gvoze" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
     <img class="_rewi8" src="https://pic.com/t51.2885-
     _1930374081979351040.jpg"></a>
    <div class="_eryrc">
     <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8" title="username1_" 
     href="/username1_/">username1_</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>

  <li class="_6e4x5">
   <div class="_npuc5">
    <a class="_pg23k _9irns _gvoze" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
     <img class="_rewi8" src="https://pic.com/t51.2885-
     _1930374081979351040.jpg"></a>
    <div class="_eryrc">
     <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8" title="username1_" 
     href="/username1_/">username1_</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>

  <li class="_6e4x5">
   <div class="_npuc5">
    <a class="_pg23k _9irns _gvoze" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
     <img class="_rewi8" src="https://pic.com/t51.2885-
     _1930374081979351040.jpg"></a>
    <div class="_eryrc">
     <a class="_2g7d5 notranslate _o5iw8" title="username1_" 
     href="/username1_/">username1_</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This results in the first user being selected each time as it just finds the first picture on the page for all the list items. I've added an output of the username text to make sure the each do loop is running through the list items in order. It successfully prints the username of a different list item every time while only opening the first user. I need a way to define the photo element as a child of each list item to be included in the each.do loop

```
Mylist = browser.ul(:class => "_8q670 _b9n99")

#Index the UL to open each user in order
Mylist.users.each_with_index do |user|

    #open user in new tab by selecting photo

    browser.a(:class => '_pg23k _9irns _gvoze').exists?
    browser.a(:class => '_pg23k _9irns _gvoze').click(:control)
    browser.windows.last.use

    #performs action and closes tab

      browser.windows.last.close


puts user
puts user.text

end
```

How do I define the element to be selected as the child of the current li in the list?

Comment: Did you try `user.a(:class => '_pg23k _9irns _gvoze').click(:control)` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani This worked! Thank you friend!

Comment: How is it is possible to use the user parameter in place of browser? @TarunLalwani

Comment: That is how iterating over a list works.  In the command `Mylist.users.each_with_index do |user|`.  you've told it to go through each item in the collection in turn, and that you want to refer to the current list item 'user'.   So when you refer to `user` in the inner code of that loop it will be the current element of the collection.  Since your collection is composed of li items from the HTML `user` will be that li along with all the html elements it contains.  Incidentally, since you are not making use of the index of the item, you can use `.each` instead of `.each_with_index`

Comment: .each_with_index is left over from my plan to create an index of all lis in the list because I wasn't sure how to iterate through each. I realized it was much simpler to use .each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop you need to use

```
user.a(:class => '_pg23k _9irns _gvoze').click(:control)
```

The reason is that a browser object can be used to search elements inside the main html page. If you use 'browser' inside the loop it will be looking at the entire HTML, and where more than one element that meets the search criteria exists, it will return the first one found.  So even through it is inside the loop, it would find the same element on the page every time.

To use the current item in the list that is being iterated you need to use the name (in this case `user`) that you've told it to assign to the list elements as it walks the list.

Comment: Ahh it makes so much sense!

Comment: edited the answer to hopefully make it a bit more helpful

Comment: Thanks @ChuckvanderLinden :-)

Comment: Thank you @ChuckvanderLinden Very Helpful!